# use diff against text files with list of files to find different files by size and/or modified date/time

Tags: find, diff

I need to compare two folders to find files that are either:

- different size and/or modified date/time
- missing from one

I cannot run `diff` against the two folders in my situation. My plan was to use `find` on both folders and save the output to two text files and then compare the two text files using `diff`.

I assume this would work but need to be sure because my source/target directories are huge and if my test shows no difference, or it doesn't find all the differences, I'd have no way of knowing if it worked or not.

If the two folders are exactly the same I assume it would work. But I question what would happen if one folder had a lot more complex sub-directories/files. Will `diff` be able to understand a folder structure printing output?

For example, I will take an inventory of the folder on one day.

```
$ find /path/to/folder -exec ls -ld {} \; > inventory-20181101.txt
...
```

I will modify a bunch of things including add, removing, editing files and adding or removing folders and sub-folders. Then another day I will take another inventory.

```
$ find /path/to/folder -exec ls -ld {} \; > inventory-20181102.txt
...
```

Then I will diff the two files.

```
$ diff inventory-20181101.txt inventory-20181102.txt
```

I assume this will work if there were no changes or the changes were minor, like just modifying files. But what happens if I add 5 levels of nested folders and then 100 files in it, and remove another top-level folder. Will `diff` be able to match up the right folders?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm not asking anyone to write a script for me. I am asking on how `diff` works and will it be able to understand differences in folder structures saved in a text file. I will put more detail in my question. Thank you!

Comment: (1) `find` is not guaranteed to list the files in a directory in any particular order.  If you run it twice in immediate succession, it will probably give the same results, but, after months of mucking around in the directory tree, things are likely to have changed.  Files that have not been modified in any way might be in the same relative order, but I doubt that even that is guaranteed. (2) `diff` is notorious for failing to "resync" after large changes, so it may report some unchanged lines as being both deleted and inserted.  It will probably not *miss* any changes.

Comment: What about simply trying it on a dummy folder to test the variations?  Create a couple of examples of each thing you're worried about and see how your approach works.  If it handles the situation, quantity won't change that.

Comment: @fixer1234 I did some tests and it worked but I want to be sure it'll work for large folders with millions of files. It sounds like from Scott's comment that `find` and `diff` will not be reliable for me.

Comment: @Scott Thank you! That helps me. I will need to find a better way to do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a reliable overview, you'll need uniform and sortable lists of the files in both directories, and a way to compare these two lists.

As has been pointed out, `diff` is meant to create readable, semantically sensible overviews of differences between files. This makes it very suitable for comparing plain text or code, but less suitable for comparing lists.
Instead, use `comm` to find commonalities or differences between two lists.

To generate a "clean" list that only contains the information you need, use the `-printf` option provided by GNU `find`. It is more efficient and robust than spawning an `ls` process for each file, and it can directly output useful information like:

- `%Tk    File's last modification time in the format specified by k`
- `%s     File's size in bytes`
- `%p     File's name`

Putting it all together:

1. List the files in each directory (in a format that only contains the required information) → `find … -printf …`
2. Sort the lists → `sort`
3. Find all lines that are *not* identical between the lists → `comm -3`: "suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)"

```
 cd dir1 && find . -printf '%T+ %s %p\n' | sort > ../dir1.txt && cd ..
 cd dir2 && find . -printf '%T+ %s %p\n' | sort > ../dir2.txt && cd ..
 comm -3 dir1.txt dir2.txt > differences.txt
```

One caveat with `%T+`: the date format will include fractional seconds (2018-11-25+14:58:43.1197033990). If your two directories are stored on different filesystems with different date accuracies, you might have to use a different (manual) date format to exclude the fractional seconds.

Comment: This is fantastic information. I will give this a try. Thank you so much!

Comment: Using `find … -printf`, `sort` and `comm` are all good ideas. A couple of minor notes: (1) The above sorts by modification time. Sorting by filename might be more user-friendly. (2) As always, when processing the output of `find`, you can get into trouble with files whose names contain newline. Files whose names contain space or tab *can* be a problem, too, especially if they *begin* with space or tab. (I should have mentioned this in [my first comment](https://superuser.com/q/1377900/150988#comment2077322_1377900).)